# Is it possible to revive this hedge?

Tags: identification, plant-health, hedge

We've lived in our house a little over a year, and over time it seems like the hedge out front has gone from a healthy green to a grey / brown. I have to admit that I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to hedge care.

I'm not sure the exact kind of plants these are, however looking at images online leads me to think they are Hinoki dwarf cypresses. From the pictures (linked below) does that seem correct?

There seems to be some new / green growth here and there but the vast majority of the plants are brown. Perhaps I have not cared for them properly.

Any tips on diagnosing and/or reviving these?

[Here are some pictures of the hedges](https://imgur.com/a/WZIaHo8?)

Comment: Not going to be nice for years, if ever.  Dig out and replace

Comment: Normally, hedging plants don't need any "care" except for pruning to stop them getting to big. Have you have exceptionally hot and dry weather? Have they been accidentally sprayed with weedkiller (e.g. you were spraying something else on a windy day). As kevinsky said, they are beyond repair. Conifers don't re-grow leaves on  branches, and the "brown stuff" will stay that way for ever unless you just chop it out and leave the hedge full of holes.

Comment: like alephzero: You may try to save it or replace, but you really need to understand the causes of such dying hedge. Check around of you (so to see if it is climate, or a disease). Check about sign of weedkiller (near the street, e.g. with other dying plants). Or maybe some winter salt. I would not replace it before I understand the causes (and personally I would try to revive it, if such dying plant is not much a problem [as separator or just esthetic].

Comment: It might be possible but it's probobly not worth the effort.

Comment: Since moving in, I've left them alone completely since they looked healthy and established. We normally have hot and dry summers. However we have suffered from bad smoke the last couple of seasons here on the West coast. Perhaps they had been getting a periodic watering during the dry months in previous years before we lived here.